# Ruby on Rails: Passing Project_ID From Last Form Submission Into New Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two steps.

Step 3 - Creates a new project.
Step 4 - Creates a new discussion post for that project that was just made in step 3.

Problem is; I cannot figure out how to get Step 4 to know the project_id for the project that was just made. Step 3 uses projects_controller and Step 4 uses posts_controller. I am thinking of using Sessions[] in def Create in the projects_controller and then somehow getting that value in def New in the posts_controller. Not working, or can't figure how to unfortunately.

projects_controller

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(params[:project])  
  session[:step3_project_id] = params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to project_step_4_path, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
redirect_to project_step_4_path(:step3_project_id=>params[:id])
```

Comment: I think you need a hash, I might be wrong:  redirect_to project_step_4_path({:step3_project_id=>params[:id]})

Comment: thanks @klochner and daniel - that does work. and puts the project_id in the URL now. I am calling it in the posts view as a hidden field value => params[:step3_project_id].  Is there a more efficient, secure way to call it from the posts_controller?

Comment: the session is the only way to hide the parameter.  If security is your concern, you should probably have something more robust than hiding the parameter (obscurity != security).